# ReflectionException: Class ArrayCollection does not exist

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I am trying to serialize entities for mobile digest. I have this Entity class:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * xxx\xxx\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="xxx\xxx\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\xxx\xxx\Entity\Music", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $musics;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\xxx\xxx\Entity\Message", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $messages;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\xxx\xxx\Entity\Location", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $locations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->musics = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->messages = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->locations = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Now when I call this line in my `DefaultController.php`:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$array = $em->getRepository('xxxBundle:User')
    ->findLatest();

$serializer = $this->get('serializer');
$response = $serializer->serialize($array, 'json'); //THIS LINE THROWS EXCEPTION
```

I have `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;` in `DefaultController.php`, but it seems the error is coming from inside `JMSSerializerBundle`.

### What have I tried thusfar

- I have tried defining the `Doctrine` annotations to start with a `\`, but that didn't help
- I have cleared my cache a million times
- I have searched for similar exceptions, but they all seem to be caused by a typo and I've checked for typos for the last 48 hours and I can't find one.

The classes were autogenerated with `app/console`.

Comment: I don't see no `namespace` declaration on top of this class file? Have you omitted it on purpose here or just c/p typo? :) Maybe, if you don't have it at all, PHP does not know how to autoload `ArrayCollection` class...

Comment: I do have a namespace declaration on top. I have checked my vendors, and `ArrayCollection` does exist in the namespace. I'm using it in another Controller and it works there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/123

Comment: Ah! Finally someone with the same exception for the same class!

Comment: I looked trough that issue and it the issue was indeed not on my side but on `Doctrine`'s side. I changed the `Annotation` classes from `ArrayCollection` to `array` and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

This solution works!
I am using JMSSerializerBundle and in Serialized Entity i have `ManyToOne` relation. I used property `$product` and of course `setter` and `getter` for that. If serializer try to get Product I got this same message i thnk because it don't understand how to convert related Entity to string/int. I adding Accessor with custom method `getProductId` and inside this method return

`$this->product->getId()`

`JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer`
`@Serializer\Accessor(getter="getProductId")`

In `OneToMany` relation, in custom `get` method I return ArrayCollection as Array `$this->statuses->toArray()`

You can also think of coonverter for relation entity, but I haven't tried (no time)